# When i am using it with db2 for pagination, my next page is giving error

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, db2, dialect

I am using spring data JPA with `DB2`. My first set of record is coming (i.e., index `0`). But when I do the next, it is giving me an error. I guess it may be because of `DB2`. When I use index `0` it is working fine. But when I use index `1` then it is giving `DataAccessException`.

```java
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(1, 10, Direction.ASC, "messageId");
```

The error occurs when using `PageRequest` with an index > 0. This leads to the below error

```java
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=OF;??( [ DESC ASC NULLS RANGE CONCAT || / MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND, DRIVER=3.69.24
```

Comment: Can you provide some example ?

Comment: I am using Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(offsetValue - 1, 10, Direction.ASC, "messageId") and repository.findById(id, pageable). but when i debug it, it is giving me error. i am using spring data jpa

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Apparently your JPA implementation generates invalid SQL.

Comment: But how it is genrating the first time record correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect class generates invalid query that why its failing you have to correct query by overiding its method.

```
replace over( order by order of inner2_)  with over()
```

Answer (score 12):

Following Abdul Gaffar Khan's advice worked for me. Here's what I had to change:

Added my exteded DB2 Dialect to my application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.my.package.to.MyDB2Dialect
spring.jpa.database=db2
```

Extended the DB2Dialect:

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.AbstractLimitHandler;
import org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LimitHandler;
import org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LimitHelper;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.RowSelection;

public class MyDB2Dialect extends DB2Dialect {

    private static final AbstractLimitHandler MY_LIMIT_HANDLER = new AbstractLimitHandler() {
        @Override
        public String processSql(String sql, RowSelection selection) {
            if (LimitHelper.hasFirstRow( selection )) {
                //nest the main query in an outer select
                return "select * from ( select inner2_.*, rownumber() over() as rownumber_ from ( "
                        + sql + " fetch first " + getMaxOrLimit( selection ) + " rows only ) as inner2_ ) as inner1_ where rownumber_ > "
                        + selection.getFirstRow() + " order by rownumber_";
            }
            return sql + " fetch first " + getMaxOrLimit( selection ) +  " rows only";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supportsLimit() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean useMaxForLimit() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supportsVariableLimit() {
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean supportsSequences() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public LimitHandler getLimitHandler() {
        return MY_LIMIT_HANDLER;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete class, saved my day.

Comment: Does anyone has any information to share, when this fix will be available for the already created issue? https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13519

Comment: Did anyone migrate this to Hibernate 6?