# Is it possible to select all columns in SQL but only selecting for every third row?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to select all columns, but each row is going to be selected for every X row.

For example, if I want to select all rows write like this:

```
@Transactional
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE job_name = :jobName ORDER BY date_time ASC LIMIT :selectedLimit OFFSET :selectedOffset" , nativeQuery = true)
List<Data> findByJobNameOrderByDateTimeAscLimit(@Param("jobName") String jobName, @Param("selectedOffset") long selectedOffset, @Param("selectedLimit") long selectedLimit);
```

But I want to extand this with something "For every X row" or something like that. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach with java code filter will select all data and filter it, which is not very efficient.

If you want to achieve that using SQL - query will depend on dialect you are using.

For example in Oracle - ROWNUM can be used, e.g.:

```
select *
  from (select ROWNUM as rn, t.*
        from Table t)
WHERE MOD(rn, 3) = 0
```

In code above - "3" is "X" from your question, meaning that "every 3rd row will be selected"

If you do not need "RN" in your results - use `Select t.*` in upper level query.

If your DB dialect does not support ROWNUM - you can add it yourself with wrapper query, following question should give you an idea how to do it:
[When i am using it with db2 for pagination, my next page is giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521999/when-i-am-using-it-with-db2-for-pagination-my-next-page-is-giving-error)

Comment: Can I use it like this `SELECT * FROM data WHERE job_name = :jobName AND  (select ROWNUM as rn, t.*
        from Table t)
WHERE MOD(rn, 3) = 0 ORDER BY date_time ASC LIMIT :selectedLimit OFFSET :selectedOffset`

Comment: It must be an easier way to do this?

Comment: Something like this should work
``SELECT t.* FROM  (select ROWNUM as rn, t.* from Table t) 
WHERE job_name = :jobName
AND MOD(rn, 3) = 0 
ORDER BY date_time ASC 
LIMIT :selectedLimit 
OFFSET :selectedOffset``

Comment: By the way. It's MySQL I'm using.

Comment: Found something now. This can print out row numbers only `SELECT * FROM (SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS rownum FROM (SELECT @row := 0) r, data) RANKED WHERE rownum % 2 = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

You can add in your invoking code this stream for example:

```
    int count[] = new int[1];
    List<Data> collect = dataList.stream()
            .peek(s -> count[0]++)
            .filter(s -> count[0] % 3 != 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where'3' it's your "selectedLimit"

Also, you can create a common utils method with this code and wrapped your findByJobNameOrderByDateTimeAscLimit in your services and getting and filtering **`List<Data>`** with help code from example.

Comment: Ah. you mean I do that in the Java code? Not MySQL code?